# What's the correct way to write a class with methods used by the whole app

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, class

I'm working on a app with several views. All of those views and their view controllers are using identical methods (it's a file parser). So to avoid duplication I thought about creating a new class only with the file parsing methods.
But now I'm not sure how to do it proper way. Which class should I choose? Is it a subclass of a Cocoa class? I guess I'm only using methods of the Foundation framework.

Or am I completly wrong and it is a module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A commonly used pattern by the iPhone SDK is by using a shared singleton instance,  you can see examples of this in `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]` or `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`.

You can achieve a pattern like this by adding a static method to your class:

```
// FileParser.h
+ (FileParser*)sharedParser;

// FileParser.m
+ (FileParser*)sharedParser {
    static FileParser* kSharedParser = nil;
    if(kSharedParser == nil) kSharedParser = [[FileParser alloc] init]; 
    // Note the over-retained object, this is by design. You should never release this object.
    // it will be destroyed when your application is killed.
    return kSharedParser;
}
```

You can then access your shared instance by importing the `FileParser.h` and writing `[[FileParser sharedParser] parseSomething:something];` anywhere in you application.

PS: This is not thread safe, read up on thread synchronization on iOS if necessary.

Comment: A better way to ensure the object won't be deallocated unexpectedly is to override `retain` and `release` so that they do nothing.

Comment: Yes, this would also make it indestructible:

`- (NSUInteger)retainCount
    {
        return NSIntegerMax;
    }`

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for. Trying it out! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a singleton object. Where there is only ever one instance of the object created. Look more into singleton objects as a design pattern.

You could also just have a class and only write class methods(+) for that class. This would only work if you don't have to store any instance variables in the class, or if those instances are declared to be static.

I think the singleton object would be the best way to do it. Though it is very similar in philosophy to ant's answer above because it would only generate one instance of the FileParser object.

Answer (score 1):

this just comes down to "how can i reuse implementations?", a problem which should be familiar.

if no state (e.g. ivars) is required, you can use this approach. also note that this may use polymorphism:

```
@interface MONStatelessFileParser

+ (MONResource *)resourceAtURL:(NSURL *)pURL;

@end
```

if state (e.g. ivars) is required, you can use this approach and then hold on to instances if needed. polymorphism also applies:

```
@interface MONFileParserWithState

@property (nonatomic, copy, readwrite) NSString * elProperty;

- (MONResource *)openResource;

@end
```

if you don't have multiple ways to read files (similar to an NSDocument) and there is no need for multiple strategies to open a file, then polymorphism can be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some class(A) to contain fileparse methods that can be used accross the views/view controllers etc. you could do it by adding A to the app delegate, instantiate the A in there and reuse the A instance trough app delegate reference.

That way you don't have to instantiate A in every view/view controller etc.